# Read data from files and paste in csv in R

Tags: r

I have a folder which contains 60 files with .circles extension. All are text files.

filename: 239.circles

contents:

```
circle17: 306 281 
circle16: 335 253
```

I want to convert it into a single csv named train.csv

with two columns: UserId and Predicted

In rows of UserId, I should get filenames e.g: 239 and in rows of Predicted i should get values in the circles separated by; e.g: 306 281; 335 253

Thanks to @Adam This is what i have done so far

```
 setwd("D:/r/social/Expt/Training")
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.circles")


readFn <- function(i) {
    f <- readLines(i,n=-1,con)
    f <-sub("^[^:]*","",f)
    f <- paste(f, collapse=';')
    return(f)
}

all.files <- lapply(files, readFn)
output <- do.call(rbind, all.files)

write.csv(output,"train.csv")
```

Output now i am getting is

1  :306 281; :335 253

I want it as  239  306 281;335 253 where under Column 1 i should get 239 (since i am reading file 239.circles) and under column 2 I should get :306 281; :335 253   (without extra : after ;)

Comment: Instead of writing a for loop why not use map or lapply? See https://rud.is/b/2016/07/26/use-quick-formula-functions-in-purrrmap-base-vs-tidtyverse-idiom-comparisonsexamples/

Comment: I think one problem in your procedure (ignoring the `for` loop): you write the `trains.csv` file every time `i` in your loop and so overwrite the old one

Comment: Please delete my previous solution and replaced with your earlier loop. I thought your actions were working earlier, but I didnt check to see that you didn't infer the `UserID` in your loop, as rightly pointed out by @wolf_wue. I'd added a solution below, which should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with `dplyr` package:

```
all_files <- lapply(files, readLines)
all_dat <- lapply(all_files, function(x)read.table(text=x)[2:3]) 

userid <- gsub(".circles", "", files) #this step extract the UserID based the "X.circle" file names
all_dat <- lapply(1:length(all_dat), function(x) all_dat[[x]] %>% mutate(UserId = userid[x]))

output <- do.call(rbind, all_dat)
write.csv(output,"trains.csv")
```

Edit:

Since there are variable lengths to each line, it would make sense to construct a data.frame for each line with id = circleX and val = sequential values in each line.

Here's a short function to do so:

```
perCircle <-  function(x){
   tmp <- read.table(text=x)
   id <- unlist(tmp[1])
   id <- gsub("circle","", gsub(":", "", id))
   out <- data.frame(id, t(tmp)[-1])
   names(out) <- c("id","val")
   return(out)
}

## example for how perCircle works:

x <- "circle830: 10788 10439 10690 10642 10551"
perCircle(x)

   id   val
1 830 10788
2 830 10439
3 830 10690
4 830 10642
5 830 10551
```

Next, let's define a function that can add in the userid to the line. Userid is based on the "X.circle" file name.

```
addUser <- function(x, id){
   out <- perCircle(x)
   data.frame(Userid=id, out)
  }

# example: the defined x above is taken from "10395.circles" line 7
addUser(x, "10395")

  Userid  id   val
1  10395 830 10788
2  10395 830 10439
3  10395 830 10690
4  10395 830 10642
5  10395 830 10551
```

The rest is quite straightforward - readLines all files as a list; define the userid base on each file name:

```
files <- list.files("./Training", pattern=".circle", full=T)
all_files <- lapply(files, readLines)

userid <- gsub(".circles", "", list.files("./Training", pattern=".circle")) 

output <- ldply(1:length(all_files), function(x) 
               ldply(all_files[[x]], addUser, id=userid[x]))
write.csv(output,"trains.csv")



output[c(100,500,1000, 1500), ] # example of 4 lines within the long data.frame

     Userid  id   val
100   10395 377 10424
500   10929 839 10984
1000  11186 989 15007
1500  12800  62 13256
```

If you want the output to have val as a vector with values seperated by ";", change the perCircle function as:

```
perCircle <-  function(x){
   tmp <- read.table(text=x)
   id <- unlist(tmp[1])
   id <- gsub("circle","", gsub(":", "", id))
   tmp <- paste(unlist(tmp[-1]), collapse=";")
   out <- data.frame(id, tmp)
   names(out) <- c("id","val")
   return(out)
}

## example:
perCircle(x)

   id                           val
1 830 10788;10439;10690;10642;10551
```

Comment: all_dat <- lapply(all_files, function(x)read.table(text=x)[2:3]) 
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 188 elements

Comment: The sample circles file can be seen on this link. There is a Training.zip file which you can download. https://www.kaggle.com/c/learning-social-circles/data.

Comment: ah. variable length for each line. That would be different to treat. I'll get back to you later.

Comment: Please see edit. I'd converted the entire training set (60 files) with the steps above. Let me know if you run into some issue or need further elaboration.